# Django only shows 15 objects...?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a very simple little Django 1.2 site, used to keep track of WEP keys cracked by students as a part of a lab, but I have run into a problem I can not figure out where it is: I have a template that lists solutions from the database, but it only lists 15 objects, even when there are many more (over 60) in the database table.

The view:

```
def index(request, message=None):
    cracks_list = Crack.objects.all().order_by('-time')
    return render_to_response('wifi/templates/index.html', {'cracks_list': cracks_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the associated template:

```
{% if message %}<p><strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
{% if cracks_list %}
    <ul>
     <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Student</td>
        <td>Key</td>
        </tr>

    {% for crack in cracks_list %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{crack.time}}</td>
        <td>{{crack.name}}</td>
        <td>{{crack.key}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No solution posted yet.</p>
{% endif %}
```

It seems very strange to me if I can not pass more than 15 objects to the template. And as far as I can tell there is nothing strange in the database. Any ideas? I assume it is something small and silly...

Comment: Do you want to list more than 15 objects in crack_list or some other object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your template input before !
If this is cracks_list print it. It will help debug !

```
def index(request, message=None):
    cracks_list = Crack.objects.all().order_by('-time')
    for  i in cracks_list:
       print i
    return render_to_response('wifi/templates/index.html', {'cracks_list': cracks_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip. It turns out that adding this code (and removing it) solved the problem. I still have no idea why it happened, but atleast things works as expected now.

Comment: Very strange. Try also `crack_list = Crack.objects.order_by('-time').all()`